# Render response page in browser from C# code

Tags: c#, forms, model-view-controller, redirect, response.redirect

I have the following code in C# which is used to post values to a form in another site

```
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            const string uri = "http://anothersite.com/index.php";
            const string myParameters = "param1=value1&param2=value2";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var htmlResult = webClient.UploadString(uri, myParameters);
            webClient.Dispose();
```

Could you please suggest how to render the response page in the browser?
I have to render the whole response page in the browser as it will be shown as it were submitted from that website itself

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC? I think you could just `return Content(htmlResult);`.

Comment: yes, I am using ASP.NET MVC4 and I have tried using `return Content(htmlResult);` but it only redirects to the page containing the form but not to the response page.